# Rails 4: select multiple attributes from a model instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How do I fetch multiple attributes from a model instance, e.g.

```ruby
Resource.first.attributes(:foo, :bar, :baz)
# or
Resource.where(foo: 1).fetch(:foo, :bar, :baz)
```

rather than returning all the attributes and selecting them manually.

Comment: What's your expected result? A hash with `name => value` pairs or an array containing just the values?

Comment: @Stefan I expect a hash to be a result

Comment: FYI, if you're just looking for an `Array` of `values` as the result and not the attribute _keys_, you can use `values_at( :foo, :bar, :baz ) #=> [ 1, 2, 3 ]`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You will use the method [`slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice).

> Slice a hash to include only the given keys. Returns a hash containing the given keys.

Your code will be.

```
Resource.first.attributes.slice("foo", "bar", "baz")
# with .where
Resource.where(foo: 1).select("foo, bar, baz").map(&:attributes)
```

Comment: `attributes` returns attribute names as strings, not symbols.

Comment: FYI, if you're just looking for an Array of values as the result and now the attribute keys, you can use `Resource.first.values_at( :foo, :bar, :baz ) #=> [ 1, 2, 3 ]`.

Answer (score 6):

How about `pluck`:

```
Resource.where(something: 1).pluck(:foo, :bar, :baz)
```

Which translates to the following SQL:

```
SELECT "resources"."foo", "resources"."bar" FROM, "resources"."baz" FROM "resources"
```

And returns an array of the specified column values for each of the records in the relation:

```
[["anc", 1, "M2JjZGY"], ["Idk", 2, "ZTc1NjY"]]
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck

Couple of notes:

- Multiple value `pluck` is supported starting from Rails 4, so if you're using Rails 3 it won't work.
- `pluck` is defined on ActiveRelation, not on a single instnce.
- If you want the result to be a hash of attribute name => value for each record you can `zip` the results by doing something like the following:

  ```
  attrs = [:foo, :bar, :baz]
  Resource.where(something: 1).pluck(*attrs).map{ |vals| attrs.zip(vals).to_h }
  ```

Comment: Useful tning, but I need `key => value` pairs to be a result.

Comment: You're right, I've added a note about mapping the results to hashes.

Answer (score 1):

#### To Fetch Multiple `has_one` or `belongs_to` Relationships, Not Just Static Attributes.

To fetch multiple relationships, such as `has_one` or `belongs_to`, you can use `slice` directly on the instance, use `values` to obtain just the values and then manipulate them with a `map` or `collect`.

For example, to get the `category` and `author` of a `book`, you could do something like this:

```rb
book.slice( :category, :author ).values 
#=> #<Category id: 1, name: "Science Fiction", ...>, #<Author id: 1, name: "Aldous Huxley", ...>
```

If you want to show the String values of these, you could use `to_s`, like:

```rb
book.slice( :category, :author ).values.map( &:to_s )
#=> [ "Science Fiction", "Aldous Huxley" ]
```

And you can further manipulate them using a `join`, like:

```rb
book.slice( :category, :author ).values.map( &:to_s ).join( "➝" )
#=> "Science Fiction ➝ Aldous Huxley"
```